# YA Book about four teenagers trying to climb a tower with magical powers

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

I remember reading this YA book back in fourth grade about four teenagers climbing a tower. This was about 10-11 years ago, and I believe the book was a bit older than that.

The details I remember about the book is that there were four teenagers with magical powers, I believe, trying to climb a tower to stop a magical force. Though, over the course of the book, some of the teens lost their powers  and suffered negative side effects from it, such as one grew older, and one lost her beauty, I believe.

I do remember being four protagonists, two males, two females each that had a certain color: Red, blue, green, and yellow. I believe the males had red and green, and the females yellow and blue. I believe the red male was the one that became old, and the yellow female is the one who lost her beauty.

Other than that, I do not remember much of the book. I do not believe it is apart of the Diadem of Worlds series, and I know for a fact that it isn't Deltora Quest.

Comment: Could this be The Tower of Geburah, by John White?